# when form submit ,the order of click function and submit

Tags: javascript, html

about click and submit
example below:

```
<form action="url" method="post">
<input type="text" id="input1"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="testFun()"/>
</form>
```

if it is possible that  function testFun run after the form's submit when we click the button to submit

if the answser is no.
why? how does the browser work when click the submit button?? the order is click function-> submit ?  is right??

Comment: submit "closes" the page

Comment: i dont understand what you mean

Comment: Do you want to run the function **before** or **after** the form is submitted ? the first is possible the second isn't (without posting the form using AJAX)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you cannot execute a function after the form has been submitted - the order of which things are executed is as follows :

- User clicks the submit button
- The `onclick` function is executed
- The browser submits the page to the `url` specified in the action of the form

You can prevent the browser submitting the page by returning `false` from the onclick handler :

```
function myfunc() {
  // do some stuff
  return false;
}
```

the submit button should then be modified like this :

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return myfunc()"/>
```

If you do wish to execute a function after the form has been submitted you need to submit the form using AJAX - this doesnt cause the browser to navigate away from the page and a JavaScript function can be executed after the form has been submitted

Comment: There are various bits of documentation around - but the most interesting is concerning the events : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_events.html

Comment: The `onlick` event of the button is triggered before the `submit` event of the form

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because the form's `action` would redirect the browser to that URL.

1 option would be to run `testFun()` on your `action` `url` page, but this might not be possible depending on what the function does.

If you are to post more information about what you are actually trying to do here, then it might help.

Comment: why？you mean when click, the click function run, and when it run over, and submit ??  is this ?

Comment: When you submit a form, it posts to the URL. Therefore your no longer on the form page, so you can't run any functions there.

Comment: yes,but if the browser will ignore the click function and only submit ?

Answer (score 1):

No, but `testFun` might (in turn) call another, asynchronous, function that wouldn't run until the form had submitted (at which point it wouldn't run at all since the browser would have left the page).

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible, after submit you are out of the scope from the current page. But if you are using an iframe for your form submit and call the function on the parent page, then I thought it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The anwswer is "It is not possible"

**Why**

Because once the browser triggers the submit event all user interaction with page is stopped. After the submit event is triggered the communication is between your browser and the webserver. This is how broswers are designed.

In your case Form submission happens because you have a form in your page and in that form you have an input of type=button. If you dont want to submit the page you can change the type of the input to button.

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvj/MBxNs/1/

Comment: It is possible - using AJAX to post the form

Comment: Right but Sking7 is using submit button for form submit, not ajax.

Comment: yes， i agree. but why? how does the browser work when click the submit button?? the order is click function-> submit ?  is right??

Comment: >>the order is click function-> submit ?  Yes

Comment: When we click the submit button form submission works because you have form in the page and you have one input in that form which of type=submit