# Spring mvc Form Submit - To load the same jsp with new additional attributes (Spring MVC annotations)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp-tags, spring-3

I have couple of select drop downs in my jsp page. Once the user chooses the value from the drop down and clicks on Go, same jsp should be reloaded with another table below(along with the details based on the selected options from the drop downs). My jsp is as below:

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="clientForm" commandName = "clientForm" action="/editFeeMaintenance">

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><strong><bean:message key="Select Client" /> </strong></td>
                <td width="8%" height="6">&#160;</td>
                <td align="left"><form:select path="client">
                        <form:option value="0">------Select Client ------ </form:option>
                        <form:options items="${clientsList}">
                        </form:options>
                    </form:select></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="client" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" /></td>
            </tr><br>

            <tr>
                <td>
                &#160;<input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="getClient()">
                </td>   
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form:form>

 <script language = "JavaScript">
    function getClient()
{

    var clientObj = document.getElementById("client");

    console.log("client value : "+clientObj);
    clientObj.actionType.value = submitType;

    return false;
    //formObj.submit();
}
</script>
```

And here is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

@Autowired
private MyService myService;

 @RequestMapping(value="/addFeeMaintainance.do",method =     RequestMethod.GET)
 protected ModelAndView populateValues(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

MyForm = new MyForm();

MyForm.setClientList(MyService.getClientList();

ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("feeMaintenance");
model.addObject("clientForm",MyForm);
model.addObject("clientsList",Myform.getClientList());

return model;
 }

  @RequestMapping(value="/editFeeMaintainance",method = RequestMethod.POST)
   protected ModelAndView selectValues(@RequestParam String client,
    @ModelAttribute("clientForm") MyForm paswForm ) throws Exception {

System.out.println("Account selected : "+paswForm.getClient());

ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("feeMaintenance");
model.addObject("clientForm",MyForm);
return model;
 }
 }
```

I'm unable to refresh the form and go to the POST method. Let me know what's missing.
And the web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

The dispatcher servlet file is as below:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan     base-package="com.controller,com.serviceImpl,com.daoImpl" />


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"
    id="viewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer"
    id="tilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/plugin/impl/tiles/springtiles-defs.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/myDS" />
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
    id="sessionFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>

     <property name="configLocation">
        <value>/WEB-INF/config/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>

    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Comment: what is your problem ? the request don't go ? the form doesn't submit ? there is a error in chrome or in java ?

Comment: The form gets submitted but I want to stay in the same jsp page which isnt working fine. I've updated my controller and jsp in the question. The POST of the controller doesnt get called at all. And there is 404 exception as soon as I click on Go.

Comment: can you post the url before and after you click on Go ?

Comment: http://localhost.xxx.xxx.com:9080/com-intranet/app/addFeeMaintainance.do this will be URL before and after since I've to load the same form again with additional attributes.

Comment: when you got 404 error the url change or not ?

Comment: No. The URL is same. when I check in httpwatch it says POST failed. In the POST parameters, I see the values being passed though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code looks ok , from both client and server sides(i havent checked if you have mapped your form object correct and you havent posted if your controller has a RequestMapping value) , but the only issue is in the form's action, in which you have not applied the specified URL in the action , so whenever you click the button , it simply calls the JS function and does not submit the form. So if you could change the

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="clientForm" commandName = "clientForm" action="">
```

to

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="clientForm" commandName = "clientForm" action="YOUR_URL">
```

and check a related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097723/when-form-submit-the-order-of-click-function-and-submit)

or check this tutorial [here](http://codetutr.com/2013/04/06/spring-mvc-form-submission/) in which he redirects whenever the form gets submitted in the same page

**Edit :**

in your web.xml you configure a servlet named Dispatcher and below you apply the request mapping to :

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>paswDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

if you have 2 servlets then you are missing some configuration or else if this is the only servlet change it to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I had given the action="/addfeeMaintenance.do" and the same is being given in the controller as : @RequestMapping(value="/addFeeMaintainance.do")
public class MyController {  } and it says it could not find the url. So I tried removing the action. Not sure what's missing.

Comment: Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri: /addFeeMaintainance.do : This is the error I get after I add action in the form.

Comment: try to add for each method you have another `@RequestMapping` and apply the request method , url value there , not above the class declaration

Comment: Yes tried that as well. Doesnt seem to work. Same error as above.

Comment: hmm the error you posted does not look like a spring MVC error , could you post your web.xml as well as with your spring-servler-config.xml

Comment: That was a typo. Dispatcher name is correct in web.xml . I changed url mapping to "/*" still the same error.

Comment: but your first page is being loaded properly ? with the client list and all?

Comment: Yes. The page will be loaded with the client list and other parameters. I should select the values from the drop down and click on Go. Another expand/collapse table should be populated in the same jsp based on the selection made. And that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: ok because i cant test it myself right now , could you try one thing , replace the url in the form's action with a different url , and change the RequestMapping to your controller's method with the post request method to listen to this url , but still return the same Model.

Comment: I should have only the POST method?

Comment: no you should have both your methods , but instead of making them listen to the same URL , mark the one with the post method to listen to the new URL you placed on the form's action . it should be like `@RequestMapping(value = "/addFeeMaintainance.do" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
protected ModelAndView populateValues(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
` and `@RequestMapping(value = "/yourFormURL",method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected ModelAndView selectValues(@RequestParam String client,
        @ModelAttribute("clientForm") MyForm paswForm )  {`

Comment: can you add the exception ? and have you removed the `@RequestMapping` from your controller declaration? you controller should only have the `@Controller ` , and your methods the `@RequestMapping`

Comment: I've updated the controller and the jsp in the question. The exception is : Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri: /editFeeMaintainance

Comment: hmm as i told you this is not a spring exception , but instead is your container exception (Must be a WebSphere) which means he do not know what to do with the request , try adding the full url path to the form , like localhost:8080/YourSpringAppName/editFeeMaintainance or at least the application's name and then the url like : /YourSpringAppName/editFeeMaintainance

Comment: I gave full path : @RequestMapping(value="/myAppaddFeeMaintainance.do",method = RequestMethod.POST) but it is giving exception Error 405: Request method 'POST' not supported  :(

Comment: add the full url to the form's action , not to the controller's method

Comment: The 400 error comes again now :) so looks like there is some issue with the path.

Comment: ok whats the full link you are hitting in your browser to get the first page ? the addFeeMaintainance.do ?

Comment: http://localhost.xxx.xxx.com:9080/com-intranet/app/addFeeMaintainance.do is the url which is working fine for GET.

Comment: **400** error means Bad request , your bean  `@ModelAttribute("clientForm") MyForm paswForm` has some properties type different than the type of arguments send with your form in `POST`.  

So check your MyForm bean if it's not working post your MyForm code.

Comment: Thanks both of you for pointing me to the right direction. There were 2 issues. One was the complete to be sent from the jsp page on submit and other one was the parameter mismatch in the @Modelattribute. Now I'm able to submit page and get the selected options in my controller's POST method.