# Will JS Handler always be called first for a Submit button (guaranteed)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp, struts2

Quick question, if I have a Submit field that submits the form,

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
```

and then a JS Click handler for it,

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
   alert('clicked');
});
```

am I guaranteed that the JS handler will **occur first**, and any server-side form submission later?

I thought that the only way to guarantee that was to `preventDefault()` in the JS handler. But if we don't do that, we can't be sure whether the JS Click handler or the Server-Side action will happen first.

```
e.preventDefault();
```

**Am I guaranteed that? So there's no need to e.preventDefault()?**

Don't suggest any "regular buttons," I must go with the Submit field, this is a Struts2 application with a Submit field that must remain on the form.

Comment: Why does it make zero sense? On Struts forms, you have a form with a Submit button that submits the form to the server. This is a "straight" form submit as opposed to an Ajax call which would only do a partial form, or a JSON. The traditional Struts app uses Submits to go to an Action or Controller. It just so happens that I need to append an additional JS OnClick to the Submit, and am wondering which one will be _guaranteed_ to happen first.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *Struts form*. It is a plain HTML. What are you trying to do with a js?

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript click event handler will probably fire before the form is submitted. That being said, there is no guarantee. It's a race condition. What you should do is decide what order you want the operations to occur in and code appropriately:

If you want the client-side JS code to fire before form submission, use `event.preventDefault();` (**NOTE:** you have to pass the event param to the click handler. You did not do this in the code you posted).

Next run your client-side code. Finally, submit the form using JS:

```
 // pass the event param to the handler function 
 $('#btnSubmit').click(function(e) {

    //prevent immediate form submission
   e.preventDefault();
   
   // do whatever you want to happen BEFORE the form is submitted   
   alert('clicked');

   // to do Ajax form submission: 

   var form = $('#btnSubmit').closest.('form');
   var data = form.serialize();
   var URL = form.attr('action');

   $.ajax({
      url: URL
      data: data;
      method: 'POST'
   });

   // OR... to do non-Ajax form submission:
    var form = $('#btnSubmit').closest.('form');
    form.submit();
});
```

Conversely, if you want the client-side code to execute AFTER the form submission, use Ajax and do a callback:

```
 $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {

   var form = $('#btnSubmit').closest.('form');
   var data = form.serialize();
   var URL = form.attr('action');

   $.ajax({
      url: URL
      data: data;
      method: 'POST'
   }).then(function () {
        alert('clicked')
   });


});
```

Comment: The downside is because this doesn't answer the question. I don't have an Ajax method, I have a Submit field going to a server-side method automatically (e.g. a Struts method). Will the Submit happen first or the JS OnClick happen first? That's the question.

Comment: Ok thanks. Are you sure about this: "It's a race condition"? That's what I thought, but my co-worker disagreed and said JS OnClick will always happen first. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11097997/1005607  - According to this post, the JS handler will always occur first.

Comment: Your friend might be right, but regardless, why not just explicitly code it to happen in the order you want?

Comment: This helped to preprocess input fields in the form. One thing though, submit button name is not in the $_POST, if it is done this way. I have many form/Submit buttons, so adding hidden input with its name to have it there fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, just make button type button, handle it with juery click handler, do what you have to do, then submit the form

```
  $("btnSubmit").click(function () {

        //do what you have to do before submit
        $('form[name=createcustomer]').submit();

    });
```

Comment: No, it must be a Submit field per application requirements hence my question

Comment: my bad, didn't see that part

Answer (score 0):

I think you confuse two events `click` and `submit`. The first one happens when you click on the button, i.e. with a mouse. However `<input type="submit">` accepts keyboard events as well. That allows to submit a form without `click`. In this way you should handle `submit` event to make sure the form is submitted.

The `submit` event is generated as a result of the `click` but if not prevented it might not happen due to the above.

You can use `preventDefault()` on the `submit` event itself to stop submitting a form. If you place it on `click` but if the `click` event isn't occurred the form is still submitted.

The order of javascript events if the button is clicked - `click` -> `submit`. You can stop any of the event by `preventDefault()` or `return false`, but it doesn't prevent form submission when javascript is tuned off.

So the answer to your question the javascript events happens first if they occurred, the action is executed second.