# What happens when I run javascript code while submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, html

here is a simple piece of javascript code

```
    $submitButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
   //Some code that changes the state of the form
   });
```

What I want to understand is:
Does the page waits to execute the callback before submitting the form?

Comment: Better duplicate: [when form submit ,the order of click function and submit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11097723/215552)

Comment: Depends on what is the submitter element. If it's that button, then yes, but if the submitter element is some other element (or the submitter element is the form itself), then that click listener is never fired.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the page waits to execute the callback before submitting the form?

Yes (although if the function triggers anything asynchronous then *that* probably won't complete before the form submits).